# Prevent default hash behavior on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a tabbed interface. Each tab has a unique id. I've enabled links pointing to that page with the appended id after the hash, and I'm now trying to circumvent the default browser behavior that opens a URL with hash at the location of the element on the page.

So:

- pageA links to pageB like this: `<a
  href="pageB.php#Tab4">Go</a>`
- pageB opens, and my jQuery activates the correct tab, but the browser has scrolled down to where `<div id="Tab4">` is located on the page.

That's exactly what I want to prevent.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There isn't a way to prevent the default hash behavior, but you can alter your hash scheme so the #tag doesn't correspond to any ID on your page. On page load, take the hash value and append a constant (ex: `_hash`), then scroll to that using jQuery.

Example:
http://mysite/page.php#tab4

page.php has `<div id="tab4_hash"></div>`

On page load, get the div by doing `tab4` + `_hash`

Comment: That's the perfect idea, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hackish but what I was looking for! and it's stupid that I didn't think of something this obvious. Thanks!

Comment: With html5 you could also use something like data-target or data-hash to select the element/div.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

This way you don't need to change element id's or anything else.

I came across the problem where I wanted to scroll down to the tab, but for some reason it scrolled past it to the bottom of the page (no, there was not a duplicate id). I think it is because the browser would scroll to the id before the content finished loading, and the extra content pushed the element above the new scroll position). I fixed it with this:

```
if(document.location.hash)
{
    window.location = document.location.hash;
}
```

the "if" statement here is mandatory or you might get an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

After you're done loading the right tab, run this:

```
window.location = '#';
```

Comment: haven't tried it but... wouldn't that scroll down and then up again?

Comment: Tested it, it works great on webkit browsers but failed on FF. Haven't tried it on IE. Will let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should just hide the element with id=hash by default
2. Аnd then, after the page loads, you make the element visible.

You can find more info here: [How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page/17950528#17950528)