# How to let the chrome forget the page scroll position?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll

For instance, I open a web page, and scroll down to some position,

then I refresh the chrome browser, the browser could scroll the previous position again

How can I use javascript or css to let the browser to forget the scroll?

I have try `$(window).scrollTop(0)`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to `.scrollTop(0)` inside a `setTimeout`?

Comment: scrollTop-ing late enough is the only thing I can think of. Say, 50ms after the page load. It seems hacky though.

Comment: @Jan it is hacky, on the other hand the whole theme is a bit hacky.

Comment: you might need to put it in the documents onready, in which case it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable brower's auto scroll after a page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617367/disable-browers-auto-scroll-after-a-page-refresh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way that I can say is to run this code on page load:

```
document.location = "#";
```

OR

```
window.scrollTo(0);
```

It set the browser viewport to the top of the page, again.

Comment: If I remember correctly, do `window.scrollTo(0)` on page load, and Chrome overrides your scroll.

Comment: I meant even `window.onload` is too soon for `window.scrollTo`. Several miliseconds after `window.onload` should do, however.

Comment: If I want the page scroll to left, not the top, what should I do?

Comment: Seconding @JanDvorak's findings. A `setTimeout` within window.onload works, but by then the window has already scrolled.

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0)` throws "cannot convert to dictionary" in Chrome and Firefox. Seems that you need to specify x and y like so: `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`

Answer (score 32):

It is resolved in the question below.

[Disable brower's auto scroll after a page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617367/disable-browers-auto-scroll-after-a-page-refresh)

```
// bypass auto scrolling.
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

Comment: This works, but required some extra tweaking for me.

Comment: this is so simple and it took 2 days to find out about scrollRestoration... thank you!

Comment: Works great! And all the major browsers now support it https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollRestoration

Comment: this is the only correct solution, as the other ones will actually FORCE the browser to autoscroll to the position 0 after window is refreshed. and you might not want to do this, but instead scroll to your own computed position

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean way of getting this done.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e){
   document.body.style.display = 'none';
});
```

By simply setting the body display to 'none' you don't have to worry about a flash of the browser scrolling to the top of the page before it is unloaded and the scroll position will automatically be reset to 0.

Comment: `body` hidden is not work; change to `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` it will done.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

JS Way:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e){
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
});
```

Jquery way:

```
$(window).load(function() {
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```