# Disable brower's auto scroll after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

Is there a way to disable the behavior where some modern browsers (Chrome and Safari) remember your scroll position on a page refresh?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is good user experience to go back to that position.

Comment: @putvande 100% agree in most cases, but a use case would be when there is large table of data that adds new data to the top, and although we can dynamically update the data, if a user refreshes for whatever reason, we don't want to bring them back to their old scroll position.  This is not the expected behavior from their perspective given this experience -- also this is just 1 use case, there are others that exist as well.

Comment: Any page that uses infinite scroll for the loading experience will have this (unexpected) problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For browsers that support history.scrollRestoration, the auto scroll behavior can be turned off:

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration

Comment: Since this is still an experimental property, does anyone know browser support?

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed. In my case, I was dealing with an angular SPA application, and was working on retaining scroll position. The browser would restore the scroll position for the previous component before the router had a chance to navigate, leading to a jumpy scroll. Ooh, those pesky browsers...

Comment: It's supported by most browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried firing this after document is ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

if that does not work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 1);
});
```

Which will push this to the bottom of the call stack

Answer (score 2):

not just for chrome,but for all i think this will work well.

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

After update of your question:

I think its better if we use some cookies or session storage.

Comment: This was my thought as well - but I am not having any luck with this kind of callback - seems like chrome does the auto-scroll after onload fires.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hoping a setTimout ends up at the bottom of the stack - I rather enforce it that we hit the scroll position we want. I still consider this a hack, I was hoping for some kind of browser event we bind to.

```
var scrollToYPos = 100;
var interval = setInterval(checkPos, 0);

function checkPos() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == scrollToYPos) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        window.scrollTo( 0, scrollToYPos );
        checkPos();               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue.  Here's the basic solution I came up with:

```
      // scroll the user to the comments section if we need to
      wt = win.scrollTop();
      wb = wt + win.height();
      // if scroll position is 0, do this (it's a fresh user), otherwise
      // the browser is likely to resume the user's scroll position, in 
      // which case we don't want to do this
      yab.loaded().done(function() {
        // it seems that browsers (consistently) set the scroll position after
        // page load.  Accordingly wait a 1/4 second (I haven't tested this to the lowest
        // possible timeout) before triggering our logic
        setTimeout(function() {
          // if the window top is 0, scroll the user, otherwise the browser restored
          // the users scroll position (I realize this fails if the users scroll position was 0)
          if(wt === 0) {
            p = self.container.offset().top;
            if(wb != p) {
              win.scrollTop(p - th - 20);         
            }
          }              
        }, 250);
      });
```

Comment: Oh and `yab.loaded` is a promise that is resolved once the window is loaded.  Equivalent to `$(window).load(function() { // ... });`

Answer (score -3):

I think the easiest way would be to trick the browser into a reload that it thinks is a new page.

```
window.location = window.location
```

All the browsers I've tested this in it works consistently.  I would personally stay away from onload callbacks as they can cause jumps during load that aren't too visually appealing.