# React - scroll to the top of the page after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React component is as follows :

```
var ContentBox = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount:function() {
    this.getContents();
  },

  getContents:function() {
    $.ajax({
      url : ......
      success:function(contents) {
        this.setState({
          contents : contents
        });
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  componentDidUpdate:function() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollTop = 0;
  }
});
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is that when the page is rendered, I want to scroll to the top of the page. The "contents" change depending on the route parameters.

I've tried the solution given in [Scroll to the top of the page after render in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js) But it's not working on mine.

UPDATE : The following worked

```
  componentDidUpdate:function() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollIntoView();
  }
```

Why doesn't `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollTop = 0;` work? Also, I've tried `$(window).scrollTop()` but that also doesn't work. I tried to put them in the "success" function of the AJAX request, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In your first code block, `findDomNode` should be `findDOMNode`... I've used that logic successfully, so may just be a typo

Comment: Nah, that's a typo when I was posting this. Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

### For react-router-dom v6+

1. Open App.js file and import:

```
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
```

2. Create a scrollTop function just above the "App" function:

```
const scrollTop = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children;
};
```

3. Wrap your routes within the scrollTop function:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <scrollTop>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </scrollTop>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is the completed code**

```
// Import all the pages (Home, about, service, contact)

import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const scrollTop = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <scrollTop>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </scrollTop>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```