# Handling scroll Animation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What is the *correct* way of dealing with scroll position in React? I really like smooth scrolling because of better UX. Since manipulating the DOM in React is an anti-pattern I ran into problem: how to scroll smoothly to some position/element? I usually change scrollTop value of an element, but this is a manipulation on the DOM, which is not allowed.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pijopebuvo/edit?html,js,output)

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => (this.node.scrollTop = i), i * 2);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const someArrayToMap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    return (
      <div ref={node => this.node = node} style={{overflow: 'auto', height: '100vh'}}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK TO SCROLL</button>
        {
            [...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap,
            ...someArrayToMap].map((e, i) => <div key={i}>some text here</div>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How to achieve this in a *React* way?

Comment: Remember that manipulating the DOM is an anti-pattern because React is essentially a DOM manager, so it must maintain awareness of everything happening in the DOM; with that said, you can always use things like `findDOMNode` and `getBoundingClientRect` to observe DOM nodes directly. Read-only is all good.

Answer (score 48):

`window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })` works for me.

You also need to check for [browser's compability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior)

Or use [polyfill](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/)

---

Edit: For the completeness' sake, here is how to dynamically polyfill with webpack.

```
if (!('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style)) {
//safari does not support smooth scroll
  (async () => {
    const {default: smoothScroll} = await import(
      /* webpackChunkName: 'polyfill-modern' */
      'smoothscroll-polyfill'
      )
    smoothScroll.polyfill()
  })()
}
```

By this dynamic polyfill, the package is loaded via ajax unless the browser supports the smooth scroll.

`polyfill-modern` is an arbitrary chunk name, which hints webpack compiler to combine packages together, in order to reduce the number of requests to the server.

Comment: If you'd like  to just "npm install" the problem away - https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill

Answer (score 47):

You can just use refs and the `scrollIntoView` method (with `behavior: 'smooth'` for smooth scrolling). It's only a few lines of code and doesn't require a package.

Say this is what you want to scroll to

```
<p ref={this.myRef} className="scrollToHere">[1] ...</p>
```

And some sort of button

```
<button onClick={() => {this.scroll(this.myRef)}} className="footnote">[1]</button>
```

to call the scroll method

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

  scroll(ref) {
    ref.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
  }
}
```

EDIT: Because this method is not yet supported by all browsers ([overview of browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)), you might want to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll).

Comment: Is this for React Native only or?

Comment: Caveat: browser support for the smooth scrolling option on `scrollIntoView` is limited to Chrome and Firefox as of November 2018

Comment: It's a Javscript method, so it does not depend on React. Here you can see the [specification and browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Because it is not yet supported by all browsers, you might want to use polyfills. I used [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) which worked perfectly for me

Comment: This seems to be the best option, if you include the polyfill. When all the browsers will implement this you can simply remove the polyfill and that's it. Thanks for this solution, works great! @sympi you should accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: @bbrinx Your link to the polyfill is pointing to the specifications page.

Comment: You're right, it seems like I can't edit the comment. The correct info is in the post.

Comment: Where did you find this answer. It works! , even on horizontal scroll.
I just change top to left.

Answer (score 24):

The Simplest way to do: -

```
window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

This simple JavaScript code is working with all browser.

Comment: This will not work on Safari as of July 2021. See other answers, mainly concerning polyfill

Comment: Thank you for a correct answer, but please note it's substantively the same as the first line of @Sang's answer, above, which was posted almost a year prior.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a small, no-dependancy solution using hooks

```js
const useSmoothScrollTo = id => {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = e => {
            if (ref.current && location.hash === id) {
                ref.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', listener, true)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('hashchange', listener)
        }
    }, [])
    return {
        'data-anchor-id': id,
        ref
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```js
export const FeaturesSection = () => {
    const bind = useSmoothScrollTo('#features')
    return (
        <section {...bind} className={classes.features}>
        ...
        </section>
    )
}
```

Then anywhere else in your app you only need to do

```js
<a href="#features">Go to Features</a>
```

Obviously, same caveats as above apply to `.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})`

Answer (score 2):

A couple good packages out there already that can handle this for you:

https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll - [Demo](http://fisshy.github.io/react-scroll-example/basic/index.html)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-component
Simple scroll to component

Hope this helps!

Comment: @PaulCo the demo at http://fisshy.github.io/react-scroll-example/basic/index.html is working fine for me

Comment: is the top left list is supposed to be clickable for scrolling or is it only  a style based on view port position ?

Comment: Yeah top menu click is scrolling to that page for me in Chrome.

Comment: Well in FF I've got the console error: ``ReferenceError: event is not defined``, never mind I'll watch this in Chromium !

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries for scrolling to anchors in React. The one to choose depend on the features you're seeking and the existing setup of your page.

[React Scrollable Anchor](https://github.com/gabergg/react-scrollable-anchor) is a lightweight library that's specifically for scrolling to anchors that are mapped to URL hashes. It also updates the URL hash based on currently focused section. [Full disclosure: I'm the author of this library]

React Scroll, mentioned in another answer, is a more fully featured library for scrolling to anchors, without any reflection of location in the URL.

You can also hook up something like [React Router Hash Link Scroll](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link-scroll) if you're already using React Router, which will then also tie into your URL hash.

Comment: Since you're the author of a library doing this, and op asked on the _how to do this in a react way_, without library. (that's how I took the question, and would like the answer to be)

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code to your **App.CSS**

```
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Make sure to use **NavLink** and **give an Id** to a particular section.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy the [react-router website](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/) in the API section, they seem to use this [scrollToDoc component](https://github.com/yasserkaddour/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-website/modules/components/ScrollToDoc.js) that is a really sweet translation of a typical VanillaJS smooth-scroll function into React which depends on [`react-motion`](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion)!

Answer (score 0):

Simple hook:

```
function useScrollTo(): [string, () => void] {
    const id = useId();
    const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    }, [id]);

    return [id, handleScroll];
}
```

And usage:

```
function App() {
    const [section2, scrollToSection2] = useScrollTo();

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={scrollToSection2}>Scroll</button>

            <div id={section2}>Section 2</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code in JavaScript that makes use of the `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method to smoothly scroll to a specified position in React:

```js
function scrollToPosition(position) {
  let startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  let distance = position - startPosition;
  let startTime = null;

  function animation(currentTime) {
    if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
    let timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    let scrollTop = easeInOutQuad(timeElapsed, startPosition, distance, 700);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
    if (timeElapsed < 700) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }

  function easeInOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d / 2;
    if (t < 1) return (c / 2) * t * t + b;
    t--;
    return (-c / 2) * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

// Usage:
scrollToPosition(500); // Scroll to the position of 500 pixels from the top
```

This code uses the `easeInOutQuad` function to create a smooth scrolling effect. The `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method is used to run the animation loop and update the scroll position. The `scrollTop` property of the `window` is updated within the `animation` function to smoothly scroll to the specified `position`.

This method does not manipulate the DOM directly, but instead uses the `window.scrollTo()` method to change the scroll position.