# Is there a simple way to animate a scrollable div from positionA to positionB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll, react-virtualized

I'm using the react-virtualized List within a functional component. It allows you to set a ref for the scorllable list div. I have an onScroll function that is currently capturing the scrollTop position of the scrolled list and storing it in fromPosition I also have a variable storing the toPosition I want to scroll to.

Does anyone have a clean way of enabling the List component to scroll from the fromPosition to the toPosition in a smooth animated way... and triggered when ever a certain piece of state changes (triggerVar)?

Comment: This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375093/handling-scroll-animation-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) method and achieve smooth scrolling by setting behavior to `smooth`.

```js
listRef.current.scrollTo({ 
  top: toPosition, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
})
```

You don't really need the `fromPosition` because `scrollTo` will scroll from the current position of the scroll.