# How to set scrollTop in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

```
environment: chrome 64;react 16;npm 5.x;node:8.x;
```

The problem is I cannot set scrollTop, it is already at 0.

I already tried the first three pages solutions in google result.

[image: css code]

[image: html code]

[image: js code]

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Not the image of code

Comment: did you tryied to set window.scrollTo(0, 0);? you can put this code on your componentDidMount.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to the top of the page after render in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the problem: should set scrollTop to it parents element.