# React Private Route higher order component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a PrivateRoute component for react. Here is my higher order component. Can you tell me what is the problem with this.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
      console.log("This is private route called");
      if (this.props.profile) {
        return (
          <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
              this.props.profile.loggedIn === true ? (
                <Component {...props} />
              ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
              )
            }
          />
        );
      }
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    profile: state.profile
  });
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
};
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? A guess is that maybe you need to extend React.Component and not the Component you are passing..

Comment: @AlexG I have implemented React.Component. Well I am not actually getting any error. Just nothing renders when I use it to visit a route.

Comment: @AlexG I am implementing it from this post https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: In the example you are implementing from, privateAuth is a Route component, not another component which renders a Route. Try simply returning the Route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can accomplish a protected route via a protected route component.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yqo75n896x

**containers/RequireAuth.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ShowPlayerRoster from "../components/ShowPlayerRoster";
import ShowPlayerStats from "../components/ShowPlayerStats";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";

const RequireAuth = ({ match: { path }, isAuthenticated }) =>
  !isAuthenticated ? (
    <Redirect to="/signin" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/roster`} component={ShowPlayerRoster} />
      <Route path={`${path}/roster/:id`} component={ShowPlayerStats} />
      <Route path={`${path}/schedule`} component={Schedule} />
    </div>
  );

export default connect(state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
}))(RequireAuth);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Header from "../containers/Header";
import Info from "../components/Info";
import Sponsors from "../components/Sponsors";
import Signin from "../containers/Signin";
import RequireAuth from "../containers/RequireAuth";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
          <Route path="/sponsors" component={Sponsors} />
          <Route path="/protected" component={RequireAuth} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

---

Or, if you want something that wraps all routes (instead of having to specify a protected route component). Then you can do something like the below.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5m2690nn6n

**components/RequireAuth.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import Header from "./Header";

class RequireAuth extends Component {
  state = { isAuthenticated: false };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (
      this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname &&
      !this.state.isAuthenticated
    ) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };

  isAuthed = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });

  unAuth = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false });

  render = () =>
    !this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Login isAuthed={this.isAuthed} />
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        <Header unAuth={this.unAuth} />
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>
    );
}

export default withRouter(RequireAuth);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Players from "../components/Players";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";
import RequireAuth from "../components/RequireAuth";

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RequireAuth>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/players" component={Players} />
        <Route path="/schedule" component={Schedule} />
      </Switch>
    </RequireAuth>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

---

Or, if you want something a bit more modular, where you can pick and choose any route, then you can create a wrapper `HOC`. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854959/7376526) (while it's written for v3 and not for authentication, it's still the same concept).

Comment: I know that this kind of comments are not allowed here..But I wanted to say 'Thank you very much'...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your render function's only return is inside of an if block, so its returning null. You need to fix the logic to just return the Route and make profile a required prop in your proptypes check instead of using an if block.

```
PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```