# Protecting a group of routes with React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

playing around with protected routes in React Router 4 and wondering whether something that I've been able to get to work is even possible.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route exact path="/auth/home" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/auth/my-profile" component={UserProfile} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/auth" />
</Switch>
```

I have these routes as shown above and I have set up a protected route called `/auth`

What I want is to use this to protect any and all routes starting with `/auth`

So in this example both

```
<Route exact path="/auth/home" component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/auth/my-profile" component={UserProfile} />
```

Would also be protected routes.

Make sense?

Comment: You could try using a route variable with a function `path="/auth/:page" component={returnComponent()}` which would the required component based on the `page` attribute in `props`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024484/7376526