# How to handle Authentication with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Trying to make certain routes require Authentication.

I have this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const menuClass = `${this.props.contentMenuClass} col-xs-12 col-md-9`;
    return (  
      <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
        <div className="App">
          <Header properties={this.props} />
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="row">
                <SideNav />
                <div className={menuClass} id="mainContent">
                  <Switch>
                    {routes.map(prop =>
                        (
                          <Route
                            path={prop.path}
                            component={prop.component}
                            key={prop.id}
                            render={() => (
                              !AuthenticationService.IsAutheenticated() ? 
                                <Redirect to="/Login"/>
                               : 
                               <Route path={prop.path}
                               component={prop.component}
                               key={prop.id}/>

                            )}
                          />
                        ))}
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {/* <Footer /> */}

        </div>

      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  contentMenuClass: state.menu,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Note: Yes the auth service works as it should.

For every route I am checking if the user is authenticated, if not then I want to redirect them to the login page, if they are then it will land on the first page with the route of "/".

All I am getting is:

> ```
> react-dom.development.js:14227 The above error occurred in the <Route> component:
>     in Route (created by App)
>     in Switch (created by App)
>     in div (created by App)
>     in div (created by App)
>     in div (created by App)
>     in div (created by App)
>     in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>     in BrowserRouter (created by App)
>     in App (created by Connect(App))
>     in Connect(App)
>     in Provider
> ```

Where am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I'd try adding `<Route path='/Login' />` explicitly at first place.

Comment: Spelling of `IsAutheenticated` is strange with `ee` in it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make a `HOC` (High Order Component) that wraps all protected routes.

Depending upon how nested your app is, you may want to utilize local state or `redux` state.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5m2690nn6n (this uses local state)

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Players from "../components/Players";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";
import RequireAuth from "../components/RequireAuth";

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RequireAuth>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/players" component={Players} />
        <Route path="/schedule" component={Schedule} />
      </Switch>
    </RequireAuth>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**components/RequireAuth.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import Header from "./Header";

class RequireAuth extends Component {
  state = { isAuthenticated: false };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (
      this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname &&
      !this.state.isAuthenticated
    ) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };

  isAuthed = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });

  unAuth = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false });

  render = () =>
    !this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Login isAuthed={this.isAuthed} />
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        <Header unAuth={this.unAuth} />
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>
    );
}

export default withRouter(RequireAuth);
```

---

Or, instead of wrapping routes, you can create a protected component that houses protected routes.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yqo75n896x (uses `redux` instead of local state).

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Header from "../containers/Header";
import Info from "../components/Info";
import Sponsors from "../components/Sponsors";
import Signin from "../containers/Signin";
import RequireAuth from "../containers/RequireAuth";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
          <Route path="/sponsors" component={Sponsors} />
          <Route path="/protected" component={RequireAuth} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

**containers/RequireAuth.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ShowPlayerRoster from "../components/ShowPlayerRoster";
import ShowPlayerStats from "../components/ShowPlayerStats";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";

const RequireAuth = ({ match: { path }, isAuthenticated }) =>
  !isAuthenticated ? (
    <Redirect to="/signin" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/roster`} component={ShowPlayerRoster} />
      <Route path={`${path}/roster/:id`} component={ShowPlayerStats} />
      <Route path={`${path}/schedule`} component={Schedule} />
    </div>
  );

export default connect(state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
}))(RequireAuth);
```

---

You can even get more modular by creating a wrapper function. You would be able to pick and choose any route by simply wrapping over the component. I don't have a codebox example, but it would be similar to this [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js/44854959#44854959).

For example: `<Route path="/blog" component={RequireAuth(Blog)} />`

Comment: This feels like a far better soloution than what I was attempting. Will try!

Comment: Was not expecting to get this but I am so greatful I did. Excellent answer and an awsome live example! I did have a typo but It still did not work as I wanted (in my original attempt). This however is a much better way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You spelled `Autheenticated` wrong.

Also, this is an assumption because you only provided the stack trace and not the `above error`, which probably says `AuthenticationService.IsAutheenticated` is not a function.

Comment: Was actually an error in the method itself. It is a typo but the method was called that way.