# using PrivateRoute in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

In this code, `authed` state becomes `true` when the user logs in, but `auth` used in `privateRoute` does not become `true` according to the below code.

```
checkauth() {
  this.setState({
    authed:true
  })
}

render() {
  function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, auth, ...rest}) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => auth === true
              ? <Component {...props} />
              : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/"   component={Firstpage} exact > </Route>
            <Route path="/signup"   component={Signup}> </Route>
            <Route path="/shop/:id" component={Shop}></Route>
            <Route path="/login"  render={(props) => <Login {...props} checkauth= 
{this.checkauth.bind(this)} />}> </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path='/newpath' component={Welcome} auth= 
{this.state.authed}/> 
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I use the states of the App component in the `PrivateRoute` function or is there any other method to do this?

Comment: Please share your `checkauth()` method.

Comment: Ok..I edited the code

Comment: I don't see anything that looks off here. Perhaps share your `Login` component as well. Also, what debugging steps have you taken? How do you know that `auth` is not true?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197248/how-to-handle-authentication-with-react-router/53197429#53197429