# How to make this.props.history available without being router to a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my App.js, I'm trying to make available the this.props.history from the 'react-router-dom'.

Relavant code is App.js is:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/" component={MainApp}/> 
        </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
    const appWithAuth = withRouter(App);

    export default <BrowserRouter><appWithAuth/></BrowserRouter>;
```

Then I get the error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

And the error points to index.js:

```
> 22 | ReactDOM.render(
  23 | <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>
  24 |  , document.getElementById('root'));
  25 | registerServiceWorker();
```

I researched this error but it seems very specific to individual problems. I did try to run npm install react-router-redux@next, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
export default <BrowserRouter><appWithAuth/></BrowserRouter>;
```

It should be

```
export default withRouter(App);
```

However, if you're trying to do authentication, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197248/how-to-handle-authentication-with-react-router/53197429#53197429).

Comment: Hey Matt, I did try with export default withRouter(App). It throws the following error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>.

And it points to index.js again:
> 22 | ReactDOM.render(
  23 | <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>
  24 |  , document.getElementById('root'));
  25 | registerServiceWorker();

Comment: Hey Matt I got it working, I should wrap the <BrowserRouter> inside index.js for it to work. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for anybody who had the same issue:
You need to wrap the reactDOM.render with BrowserRouter for it to work:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider></BrowserRouter>
 , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Thanks to Matt for the clarification