# Wanting to redirect a page to another page from another website that can only be accessed via a login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

There is a WordPress website that I don't have access to yet. There is a tool on the website that is outdated.

There is a second website that takes you to a login page. Once logged in, you can access one of the modules on it, which is another tool. The second website is React on the front-end and has a Java/Maven back-end.

I want to redirect the page from the first website (the old tool) to the page from the second website (the new tool), without having to log in on the second website.

What would be the best way to do this? I've never had to do a similar task before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197248/how-to-handle-authentication-with-react-router