# React Renders at the bottom of my component! no the top

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

when i click on one of the Links in the mobile view, it renders a new component for the product details page.

However the rendered view always starts at the bottom ..

how can i change this to always display the new component from the top ??

Comment: Your Question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js). :)

Comment: thank you @SebastianWaldbauer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to the top of the page after render in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

Comment: what if it was on a stateless component ?

Comment: ok so this is what i did : const componentX = ({ something }) => {

  window.scrollTo(0, 0)

return (<div>some HTML code</div>)
}

Answer (score 1):

for stateless component with the help of hooks you can achieve this by doing:

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
}, [])
```