# How to fix Gatsby JS Link component retaining scroll position and not resetting to top

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm setting up a website using Gatsby 2.2.10 and the Link components are retaining the scroll positions of the previous page and not scrolling back to the top when they're clicked.

```
<div className="Footer__legal body">
 <p>© {new Date().getFullYear()} My Nice Company</p>
 <Link to="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</Link>
 <Link to="/page-2">Page 2 Link component</Link>
</div>
```

Expected behaviour:

When you click 'Privacy Policy', 'Page 2' or any page at the bottom of the website, I expect the page to load with user being back at the top.

Actual Behaviour:

User stays at scroll position of the current page

Comment: Repo and netlify links are not available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` set on `body`, you'll have this issue!

Comment: Welcome, and Thanks for your contribution. Please consider updating your post with an ` edit` to explain why this happens, or a link to documentation indicating that this is the defined/expected behavior.

Comment: This actually was the fix for me–I had overflow: auto on my body. I'm not sure why this is the case, but hopefully someone can help explain why.

Answer (score 9):

You can also modify `gatsby-browser.js` and implement a hook for each scroll update:

```js
// in gastby-browser.js
exports.shouldUpdateScroll = ({
  routerProps: { location },
  getSavedScrollPosition,
}) => {
  const { pathname } = location
  // list of routes for the scroll-to-top-hook
  const scrollToTopRoutes = [`/privacy-policy`, `/page-2`]
  // if the new route is part of the list above, scroll to top (0, 0)
  if (scrollToTopRoutes.indexOf(pathname) !== -1) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }

  return false
}
```

You will find the code for [`shouldUpdateScroll` on GitHub](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/cache-dir/navigation.js#L122-L148) or in the [documentation for `shouldUpdateScroll`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#shouldUpdateScroll) on the GatsbyJS website.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm not having any luck. Any Link I open takes me to the new route scrolled down the same as I was on the previous page.

Comment: @jj0b Did you restart your gatsby command? Changes in `gatsby-config.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` etc. are effective after restarting your develope/serve/build process.

Comment: I did. The thing that finally worked for me was using document.getElementById("WhateverIdYouWantToScrollTo").scrollIntoView() instead of window.scrollTo(0,0). I happened to use it in a useEffect hook but I'm sure any of the other ways of triggering that line a the right time would likely have worked for me. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js/59079771#59079771

Comment: This worked, I just put the `window.scrollTo()` without condition as I wanted to have it on all page navigations.

Comment: Thank you, this finally fixed my scroll issue with Gatstby v4.13.1

Comment: thanks this worked, in firefox but not worked on chrome must spam refresh

Answer (score 5):

If your page is a functional component, you can use the `useEffect` hook to scroll back to the top of the page, assuming that you are using `graphql` and so your component takes some data as an argument. This way every time that `data` changes, you scroll to the top of the page(works similar to componentDidUpdate).

```
const PageCmp = ({ data }) => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0,0)
    }, [data])
    ...
}
```

Comment: I needed to add a `setTimeout(() => {...}` around the `window.scrollTo()` call for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), [])` solved the issue for me. I was having the problem only on firefox but not on chrome. Idk what was causing the issue but it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I had set scroll-behavior: smooth, on the html element like this:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

After removing this property new pages would be opened without any scroll.

Comment: Same for me. However, it's working for most of the links and defaulting for very few links.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is an old question, but I've recently faced the same odd behavior. Turns out my problem was different from all other solutions I've seen in the internet so far.

Gatsby uses a package called `gatsby-react-router-scroll`. This package manages Gatsby's scroll behavior. This behavior is mainly implemented in [Scroll Handler](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-react-router-scroll/src/scroll-handler.tsx) component. This component only scrolls up in `componentDidUpdate` method, and not in the `componentDidMount` one. I've added a `debugger` in the `componentDidMount` method and ScrollHandler component was being re-mounted at each navigation.

The fix was to figure out why this component was being mounted and remounted at each navigation. In my case, I had a `React.StrictMode` component on `wrapRootElement` function in my `gatsby-browser.js`. Removing StrictMode made ScrollHandler component stable, thus solving my problem.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. But [KMA Badshah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446807/8087608) did the trick for me. Wished you added some code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a workaround by converting index.js page into a class-based component and then added

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
```

Not the cleanest fix nor do I know why it wasn't scrolling automatically, going to a JS meet up next week so will ask the question then and post a follow up if I get an answer.

I have a feeling it's something to do with my styles, as I started a new project and the Gatsby-cli had no issues.  Will be refactoring styles to see if this fixes the issue.

**Note:** Returning to this following Michael's answer, it also related to an `overflow: hidden;` style I had on the body, removing this also fixed my issue.

Comment: Returning to this following Michael's answer above, it also related to an `overflow: hidden;` style I had on the body, removing this also fixed my issue.

Comment: I am glad, that I could have helped. I'd like to mention one little thing: Instead of adding a comment, think about editing your answer and adding something like "**Note: ...**"

Comment: @JackDavidEvans - I was having this problem and I did have a overflow: hidden on my body!

removing that solved this for me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had `html {height: 100%}`. Removing that rule seemed to have solved the problem.

I also have `gatsby-plugin-transition-link` in my project, which has added more wrappers around my main content.

Answer (score 1):

In my CSS, I had

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

because it was the only way to fix a mobile-safari-only bug (my favorites!)

If you also can't get rid of `overflow` properties, I suggest this:

```js
// in gatsby-browser.js
export function shouldUpdateScroll(prevRouterProps, { location }) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
  body.scrollTop = 0
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a header set with `position: fixed;` and then a div with `margin-top: 100px;` so my content starts below the header (that has a 100px height). I had the scrolling issue until I changed **margin** to **padding**: `padding-top: 100px;`

Comment: similar problem, just convert margin to padding.

Answer (score 0):

To further some of the answers above, I had to stick a time out in the useEffect to get it to work consistently. Seems to work with a timeout as little as 1ms.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let windowScrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    clearTimeout(windowScrollTimeout)
  }, 1)
}, [])
```