# How to make Scroll to top if user refresh page with Gatsby js

Tags: reactjs, scroll, gatsby

im read documentation gatsby with [scroll-restoration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/scroll-restoration/) but this not working in my case, so im find this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/12560) yeah, if im spam refresh page back to top slowly upwards so im find something diferent not use hook useScrollRestoration on gatsby but use plugin [shouldUpdateScroll](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/scroll-restoration/) in browser-gatsby.js and im find something [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181253/16945930) in stackoverflow is workingjust browser firefox ,but not chromium family like chrome , opera, and edge.

so , how this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181253/16945930) worked in another browser ?

Answer (score 0):

okay im already this stuck , i hope this answer help everyone with same case.
im add something with this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181253/16945930

and this fix my problem

```
// in gastby-browser.js
exports.shouldUpdateScroll = ({
    routerProps: { location },
    getSavedScrollPosition,
  }) => {
    const { pathname } = location
    // list of routes for the scroll-to-top-hook
    const currentPosition = getSavedScrollPosition(location)
    const scrollToTopRoutes = [`/id/`, `/en/`]
    // if the new route is part of the list above, scroll to top (0, 0)
    if (scrollToTopRoutes.indexOf(pathname) !== -1) {
      window.scrollTo(currentPosition * 0, 0)
      console.log(scrollToTopRoutes.indexOf(pathname))
    }
  
    return false
  }
```

at documentation [shouldUpdateScroll](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#shouldUpdateScroll)

we can take number with function getSavedScrollPosition and add operator * with value 0 so everthing get dta location scroll page become 0

this worked in browser firefox and chromium family(chrome, opera, edge ). but dont know with safary browser