# Need scroll to be at top on new page load - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a multipage application. I need to implement scroll to top automatically when I traverse to a new page. I have tried following:

**ScrollToTop.js** this is placed inside component folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

And **App.js**

```
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollToTop from './common/components/ScrollToTop'
const Appnew = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Appnew/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)
const App = (props) => {
{Appnew()}
}
```

This is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Scroll to the top of the page after render in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your hoc. Assuming your `Appnew` has components encapsulated with `Route`, it should work.

Just used your hoc and [prepared a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-to-top-issue-fix-oo0ci?file=/src/App.js) which is working fine. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change this

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }
```

by

```
componentDidMount() {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
     });
 }
```

What it will do it's when the component is mounted it will scroll to the top.

Also you could use the event below which listen the DOM and when it is loaded do whatever you want to

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // Your code
});
```