# Scrolling to top on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my page to scroll to the top on page load, it semi works just now, but if I have scrolled down further than the size of my target page it no longer works, seems strange, any simple fix?

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
  }, []);
```

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

> ```
> window.scrollTo(0, 0)
> ```