# Scroll to an element when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to scroll to a `div` element when I click a button. But unfortunately the scroll isn't working. But my `console.log()`

I read this [Scroll to the top of the page after render in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js) and this [How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

function TeamOld() {
    const myRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        <div>
                <button class="button is-primary is-outlined mr-4 mb-2" onClick={() => {myRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0); console.log("Test")}}>Click me</button>
            ...
            <div className="" style={{ width: "100%" }} ref={myRef}>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TeamOld
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `scrollIntoView` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
`scrollTo` is used to scroll the element itself (assuming you have scrollbars inside your div).