# How to fix react auto scroll issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to create my project. The issue I am having is if I scroll to any page and then to go another page I end up in the same place on the top of the page. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: does it solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js

Comment: please read how to ask questions on stackoverflow and edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}

useEffect(() => {
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Window.scrollTo` or `element.scrollIntoView` function to resolve the problem

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
```

or if you want scroll behavior

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

but this is not the best way to do it in every component so you can use custom hooks to implement and use it everywhere

```
import react, { useEffect } from "react";

const useTop = function () {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
};

export default useTop;
```

[click to view demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-euler-r1fco?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

let's figure it out of the `element.scrollIntoView` function and the use case
if we need to scroll to an element but we don't know the height and width of the element from the viewport so that's why we just use element.scrollIntoView function to resolve that.
we can manually calculate the height and width of the element from the viewport using the `element.getBoundingClientReact` function but we need a lot of boilerplate code needed to implement

with the use of custom, hooks can use scroll events whenever we needed

```
const useTop = function () {
      const scroll = (ref) => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth" });
      };
    
      return { scroll };
    };
    
    export default useTop;
```

[click to view demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jovial-dawn-15st7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)