# React-reveal on scroll is being affected by Scroll-to-top component on location change

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, scrolltop, animate-on-scroll

I'm building a website and I'm using [react-reveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reveal) to animate content on my pages(home page about page, and contact page) as I scroll to them,

Then I noticed that the way react navigate pages is through the **'react-router'** which just renders a new component when a link is clicked(or location changes) and not refreshing the whole page entirely,

This means whenever I switch to a new page, the scroll/scroll-bar position on the previous page does not refresh.
Then I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js): a `scrollToTop()` function that runs every time a new page is rendered

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage';
import AboutPage from '../pages/AboutPage';
import ContactPage from '../pages/ContactPage';

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
};

function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path='/contact' element={<ContactPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But now the problem is whenever I navigate to a page, it scrolls to the top and all the animations that **react-reveal** offers have been triggered already while the `scrollToTop()` ran on page render.

So now when user scrolls down the page, there are no animations to display

> #### Question:
>
> - How do force my page to start at the top without using the `scrollToTop()` function
>
> ##### or
>
> - How do I activate `react-reveal` only when the page has scrolled to the top

I have searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188994/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-after-render-in-react-js) and only found solution of `scrollToTop()`, but this removes the **reveal on scroll** effects