# Scrolling to the center of a div when loading the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to find out how to achieve centered alignment when loading a page. I have a div which is 4000x2000 pixels and a text which is centered within this div. Now when reloading I want to scroll to the X so that the X is in the middle. I have already found something on the internet, unfortunately it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let testDiv = document.getElementById("containerTest");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        testDiv.scrollTop = testDiv.scrollHeight/2;
        testDiv.scrollLeft = testDiv.scrollWidth/2;
    })
```

```css
#containerTest{
            width: 4000px;
            height: 2000px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        .inner-div{
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            font-size: 50px;
            position: relative;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div id="containerTest">
    <div class="inner-div">X</div>
</div>
```

This is how it should look after loading:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Buggies made a good point about browsers auto scroll after refresh

If you want a more robust solution to scroll to the center, try using `scrollIntoView` which works even if there's content above/to the left of the container

```
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        let testDiv = document.getElementById("containerTest");
        testDiv.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "auto",
          block: "center",
          inline: "center",
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is auto scroll from browser, info and solution you can find here: [Disable brower's auto scroll after a page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617367/disable-browers-auto-scroll-after-a-page-refresh)

The second problem is that you are scrolling with `containerTest` but it is not scrollable. You want to scroll with body/window

example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let testDiv = document.querySelector('#containerTest')
    window.scroll(testDiv.scrollWidth / 2, testDiv.scrollHeight / 2)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ScrollTopHelper() {
const location = useLocation()

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo( X-Coordinate,  Y-Coordinate)
    console.log('wael')
}, [location])
return null
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).