# jQuery smooth scrolling to link on other page with offset

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have started with the code from CSS-Tricks and it works well with the offset. The problem is that the site has a fixed header so I need it to apply the offset when navigating to an internal link from another page. Currently it is getting cut off.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top-144
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The page in question is http://marketingmo.wpengine.com/services/#brand-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no native js function that can prevent the hash anchoring on page load. But there is a good workaround for this and it is found on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page#answer-3659116). I've used this method before and it works very well.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var hash = location.hash
    if (hash && $(hash).length) {
        var target = $(hash).offset().top;
        var headerH = $('header').height();
        $(window).scrollTop(target - headerH)
        /*
        //or with animate, 
        //but you'll need to reset the scrollTop to 0 (the top) first:
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target - headerH}, 1000);
        */
    }
}, 1);
```

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. I used that bit of code in addition to the original code and they play very nicely together. Thanks Mark!