# No anchor link when refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, anchor

I have several anchor links on my webpage. I'd like to make it so that when the user refreshes/reloads the page, the page does *not* follow the anchor link in the URL, and goes to the top of the page. I have tried stripping everything after the `#` on the backend, but I can't imagine there isn't a more elegant solution. Is there a way to do this on the front-end, using HTML/JS?

Comment: you want the browser to follow your anchors when someone reload or refreshes the page ?

Comment: If you want to do something when the page loads you could put something on the load event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: Is this browser dependent? Neither Chrome nor Firefox seem to follow the anchors when I refresh, they stay in the same location you were scrolled to previously.

Comment: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){$(window).scrollTop(0);});`

Comment: @M.Tanzil I **do not** want to follow the anchor links. I want it to behave as if the anchor links weren't in the URL at all.

Comment: So you want when there is click on the links there is # added to the URL and the page goes to the top, and you want the page don't need to go to the top of page but remain as it is ?

Comment: are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page)?