# Hash anchor scrolling - how browsers are choosing an element to scroll in?

Tags: html, anchor

In some cases browsers choose bad element for vertical scroll, when URL-hash in an  anchor has passed. For example `overflow:hidden` element may choose.

I want to know, how the browsers are choosing an element to scroll in, when URL-hash is passed? Or how to prevent the bug and always use `body` or `html` containers for scrolling?

In my case - the structure is:
`html` -> `body {display:flex;flex-direction:column}`  -> `div` -> `section {display:flex}` -> ... -> `div#my_anchor`
And `section` had choosed for scroll. I tried to turn off a scrips - no effect, it means scroll does browsers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you tried to stop browsers from scrolling to `my_anchor` when `#my_anchor` is in URL? You can try using the javascript code in the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I do the same - manual scroll with JS. But i'm interested - why the`section` with hidden overflow is choosed .. By the way`window.scrollTo(0, 500)` - not works, it try to scroll `body` element instead `section` choosed for hash scroll.

Comment: Sorry I can't answer. Maybe it is trying to scroll to `my_anchor` but there is some bug or specific problem with scrolling to `display:flex` elements. `flex` is pretty new so maybe it is a bug that hasn't been fixed.

Comment: What if you put `display:flex` on a div container instead? Like this: `html > body > div {display:flex;flex-direction:column} > div > section > ...`