# Remove scrolll after page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

- I have [wordpress site](http://civilwarboots.net/etacanada/produit/demande-dautorisation-de-voyage-electronique-ave/) in which after complete one step of form
  it redirect to second part but because of id added in URL it [scroll
  down](http://prnt.sc/cz2r72) where page id in hidden. But i want to prevent scrolling and
  look like [this](http://prntscr.com/czk7cp)
- After complete first step it [scroll down](http://prntscr.com/czk8qi) page also want to remove
  this without change in url and hidden id.

  Any Possibility by JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page)

Comment: answer already given here:How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?

Comment: thanks for suggest but that no work to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have Solved It myself.It's HTML issue.