# Stop browser from jumping to an id element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want the browser to jump to an given id in :

`<a href="documentation-creating-model.php#learningDiagnosis">Learning diagnosis</a>`

Few links direct to another page so i need the anchor tag. But in the same page i have written a code to scroll to a proper location.

I have tried:

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
e.preventPropogation();
```

none of the above works.

Basically when on same page i want to override the default scrolling. I have written scrollTop but it doesn't work since the default scrolling take place

Comment: where have you tried those?

Comment: Remove the id onclick anchor tag it not redirect

Comment: @madalinivascu on jquery click function

Comment: @whoami it is located in a menu. so when that link redirects to a div in the same page, i want to apply my function but if it is in some other html page i want to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page)

Comment: @N15M0_jk i dont want to keep the scroll to the top though

Comment: Can you show me some more code?

Comment: example js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r0ofctct/

Comment: @GovindSamrow i added a fiddle in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out # in `attr` of `a` tag:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    var hasUrl = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[0];
    alert(hasUrl == "")
    if(hasUrl == "") {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('redirect');
    }
})
```

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj3Lcw67/)

Comment: Well anchor tags referring to other pages will also have a hash tag

Comment: Then you need to added proper html in a fiddle of ques body for better answers

Comment: I've edit the answer and hope this will be works for you

Comment: id like to add a detail. format always will be href="docname.htm#id" even if on same page. ima handeling it in on click. "return false " isn't working for me

Comment: return false and e.preventDefault() isn't working that is the main problem