# e.preventDefault() to prevent anchor jumping to the ID not working on anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have the following jQuery/JS that triggers some stuffs when an element is clicked:

```
$(tabs).click(function(e) {
    tabs.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $(tabIDs).removeClass('js_tab_area_show');
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('js_tab_area_show');

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('worked');
});
```

`tabs` here has been initialised before the function and has selected the elements I want to target. All the things above are already working. However, I now want to disable the anchor element (i.e. `tabs` in this case) from scrolling to the element with the ID that is contained within the `href` properties of my anchors. I tried looking around and many suggested `preventDefault()` to prevent scrolling. However, it did not work for me. The only difference I mostly see is they have a named function dedicated for handling click events that is called from within the click function. Mine on the other hand did the above. The `alert('worked')` did fire indicating the code executed until the end. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I don't see what code is controlling the scrolling in your example.

Comment: `event.preventDefault` is not used to be stop the function right there. If you want to stop fire right before `alert('worker')`, it should be `return false`.

Comment: @Kai It's not that I want to stop the function from executing there and then. I want it to prevent the `a` from scrolling to the `div` which has the same id that is contained within `a`'s `href`. Look here for more info, this is what I meant by the 'suggestion' I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page/17950528#17950528

Comment: @WealthyPlayer so please try to `return false` at the end :D.

Comment: @Kai I placed `return false;` after `alert('worked')` and it still did scroll to the `div` element.

Comment: can you recreate your problem in codepen?

Comment: @BhushanBabar Perhaps later. I'll tag you again when I am available to recreate the problem in Codepen, tasked w/ something else for now.

Comment: @BhushanBabar It oddly worked in my codepen, but not in my project. Could you roughly guess why? Codepen here: https://codepen.io/takenoteiamhere/pen/aXEXxE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `href` Modification

Instead of over complicating your JavaScript/jQuery or CSS do the following.

> ```
> <a href="#/">I DON't JUMP</a>
> ```

☝ Just add a forward slash: `/`

If you have a ton of links and no server-side utilities available to you see **Demo 2**. It has a simple JavaScript link collector.

---

### Demo 1

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-size: 64px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 400px 0;
}

a:first-of-type {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

a:last-of-type {
  color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <h2>⇩</h2>
  <a href="#">Click me.<br>I JUMP.</a>
  <a href="#/">Click me.<br>I DO NOT JUMP.</a>
</main>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(lnx => {
  if (lnx.getAttribute('href') === '#') lnx.setAttribute('href', "#/");
});
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-size: 64px
}

main {
  margin: 400px auto;
}

a:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scroll Down</h1>
<h2>⇩</h2>
<main>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
  <a href='#'>WE DON'T JUMP</a>
</main>
```

Comment: If this is the case though, I see no point in using `a` at all. Admittedly, I probably shouldn't have used `a` because I'm implementing `tab`; any other element like `div` would have worked fine too with different concepts applied to my handler. So more questions: 

**1.** Should I change my `a` to `div`, which means tweaking my JS concept? ---- **2.** What if I still wanted to use my above code (`a` containing `href` that points to target elem) because my JS code relies much on the `href` that the targeted `a`s have? Is it possible to disable the scrolling/jumping through JS/jQuery?

Comment: 1. No, unless you have the time to spare. 2. Depends are the hrefs being used with the `:target` selector, if so I would change that because it isn't very flexible nor that useful. 3. Yes it's possible to disable scrolling ... have you tried placing `e.preventDefault();` on the first line within the function. I always do and `e.preventDefault();` has never failed me.

Comment: 1. Okay, thank you. **2.** Nope, they aren't. I'm merely running a `for` loop to get all the `href` of the `a`s and save them in `tabIDs` above that I will use for the next functions. **3.** I did, this is the main problem here. On the code above, I have already used `e.preventDefault();`, please take a look, albeit on the 3rd last line of the code. It shouldn't matter though. I also tried `return false;` as suggested by the comments to my question above. Also didn't work.

Comment: *"I have already used e.preventDefault();, please take a look, albeit on the 3rd last line of the code. It shouldn't matter though."* Order matters in many aspects of programming. When dealing with events there is an order in which events trigger capture propagate etc. I'd test your code but I'll need the HTML as well.

Comment: Hello, I've just placed `e.preventDefault()` as the first line to be executed within my `click` handler function. Still did not work. I'll tag you with the codepen when I have it.

Comment: Hello again, oddly it worked in my codepen, but not in my project. See my codepen here: https://codepen.io/takenoteiamhere/pen/aXEXxE

Comment: Gave some elements classes (jQuery is very versatile you can use classes easily 90% of the time). Using `data-*` attributes with `.data()`  method. https://codepen.io/01/pen/PVQmzB?editors=1010

Comment: Yes I eventually used `data-id` to imitate the `href`. I'm still REALLY CURIOUS why my `e.preventDefault()` didn't work on my code, but worked on codepen, though. Any idea why?

Comment: If I reviewed the code in its real environment I could most likely find the issue or at least point you in the right direction.