# When I scroll in full screen, my last transition does not show up

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

So, the best way to see this problem is for me to post the code.
I am not entirely sure where I went wrong and I've been searching and searching, but I can't seem to make it show up unless I make the browser smaller. So on a phone, it would look fine, but on the browser, it doesn't show the last signup part. That and when it is in mobile version/size the last signup area isn't centered and I can't figure that out either

```js
skrollr.init({
  forceHeight: false
});

/*!
 * Plugin for skrollr.
 * This plugin makes hashlinks scroll nicely to their target position.
 *
 * Alexander Prinzhorn - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr
 *
 * Free to use under terms of MIT license
 */
(function(document, window) {
  'use strict';

  var DEFAULT_DURATION = 500;
  var DEFAULT_EASING = 'sqrt';

  var MENU_TOP_ATTR = 'data-menu-top';
  var MENU_OFFSET_ATTR = 'data-menu-offset';

  var skrollr = window.skrollr;
  var history = window.history;
  var supportsHistory = !!history.pushState;

  /*
   Since we are using event bubbling, the element that has been clicked
   might not acutally be the link but a child.
  */
  var findParentLink = function(element) {
    //Yay, it's a link!
    if (element.tagName === 'A') {
      return element;
    }

    //We reached the top, no link found.
    if (element === document) {
      return false;
    }

    //Maybe the parent is a link.
    return findParentLink(element.parentNode);
  };

  /*
   Handle the click event on the document.
  */
  var handleClick = function(e) {
    //Only handle left click.
    if ((e.which || e.button) !== 1) {
      return;
    }

    var link = findParentLink(e.target);

    //The click did not happen inside a link.
    if (!link) {
      return;
    }

    if (handleLink(link)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  /*
   Handles the click on a link. May be called without an actual click event.
   When the fake flag is set, the link won't change the url and the position won't be animated.
  */
  var handleLink = function(link, fake) {
    //Don't use the href property (link.href) because it contains the absolute url.
    var href = link.getAttribute('href');

    //Check if it's a hashlink.
    if (!/^#/.test(href)) {
      return false;
    }

    //Now get the targetTop to scroll to.
    var targetTop;

    //If there's a data-menu-top attribute, it overrides the actuall anchor offset.
    var menuTop = link.getAttribute(MENU_TOP_ATTR);

    if (menuTop !== null) {
      targetTop = +menuTop;
    } else {
      var scrollTarget = document.getElementById(href.substr(1));

      //Ignore the click if no target is found.
      if (!scrollTarget) {
        return false;
      }

      targetTop = _skrollrInstance.relativeToAbsolute(scrollTarget, 'top', 'top');

      var menuOffset = scrollTarget.getAttribute(MENU_OFFSET_ATTR);

      if (menuOffset !== null) {
        targetTop += +menuOffset;
      }
    }

    if (supportsHistory && !fake) {
      history.pushState({
        top: targetTop
      }, '', href);
    }

    //Now finally scroll there.
    if (_animate && !fake) {
      _skrollrInstance.animateTo(targetTop, {
        duration: _duration(_skrollrInstance.getScrollTop(), targetTop),
        easing: _easing
      });
    } else {
      defer(function() {
        _skrollrInstance.setScrollTop(targetTop);
      });
    }

    return true;
  };

  var defer = function(fn) {
    window.setTimeout(fn, 1);
  };

  /*
   Global menu function accessible through window.skrollr.menu.init.
  */
  skrollr.menu = {};
  skrollr.menu.init = function(skrollrInstance, options) {
    _skrollrInstance = skrollrInstance;

    options = options || {};

    _easing = options.easing || DEFAULT_EASING;
    _animate = options.animate !== false;
    _duration = options.duration || DEFAULT_DURATION;

    if (typeof _duration === 'number') {
      _duration = (function(duration) {
        return function() {
          return duration;
        };
      }(_duration));
    }

    //Use event bubbling and attach a single listener to the document.
    skrollr.addEvent(document, 'click', handleClick);

    if (supportsHistory) {
      window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
        var state = e.state || {};
        var top = state.top || 0;

        defer(function() {
          _skrollrInstance.setScrollTop(top);
        });
      }, false);
    }
  };

  //Private reference to the initialized skrollr.
  var _skrollrInstance;

  var _easing;
  var _duration;
  var _animate;

  //In case the page was opened with a hash, prevent jumping to it.
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page
  defer(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);

      if (document.querySelector) {
        var link = document.querySelector('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]');

        if (link) {
          handleLink(link, true);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}(document, window));

var s = skrollr.init( /*other stuff*/ );

//The options (second parameter) are all optional. The values shown are the default values.
skrollr.menu.init(s, {
  //skrollr will smoothly animate to the new position using `animateTo`.
  animate: true,

  //The easing function to use.
  easing: 'sqrt',

  //How long the animation should take in ms.
  duration: function(currentTop, targetTop) {
    //By default, the duration is hardcoded at 500ms.
    return 1000;

    //But you could calculate a value based on the current scroll position (`currentTop`) and the target scroll position (`targetTop`).
    //return Math.abs(currentTop - targetTop) * 10;
  },
});

$(".icon-bookmark").click(function() {
  $("#placemark").addClass("placemarked");
  $(".icon-bookmark").addClass("pressed");
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika");
@import url("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.css");
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css");

html {
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #DDD7D1;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/52524/NewYork2_bg.png");
}

.notPlacemarked {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.placemarked {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
}

.container {
  background: #00C993;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2050px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 24px;
}

.section {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

#sect1 {
  top: 400px;
}

#sect2 {
  top: 1000px;
}

#sect3 {
  top: 1500px;
}

#footer {
  top: 2000px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#twitter {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

#rocket {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

#hiddenIcon {
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.anchor {
  height: 100px;
}

band2 h2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.explanation {
  min-width: 12.42em;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.explanation-right {
  min-width: 12.42em;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5%;
  width: 40%;
}

#phone {
  background: #DDD7D1;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 0 #BCB1A5;
  padding: 50px 18px 50px 18px;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}

#screen {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#topBar {
  background: #00C993;
  height: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#mc_embed_signup {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #00C993;
}

#mce-EMAIL {
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
}

#mce-EMAIL:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe {
  border-style: none;
}

.icon-bookmark {
  float: right;
}

.icon-bookmark:hover {
  color: #FFC52F;
}

.pressed {
  color: #FFC52F;
}

h1,
h3 {
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1em;
  /*margin-bottom: 1em;*/
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.button {
  background: #DDD7D1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2em 0 #BCB1A5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  /*transition cross-browser stuff*/
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Safari 3.2+, Chrome */
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Firefox 4-15 */
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Opera 10.5–12.00 */
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Firefox 16+, Opera 12.50+ */
}

.button:hover {
  background: #BCB1A5;
}

a.arrow {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  /*transition cross-browser stuff*/
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Safari 3.2+, Chrome */
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Firefox 4-15 */
  -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Opera 10.5–12.00 */
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
  /* Firefox 16+, Opera 12.50+ */
}

a.arrow:hover {
  color: #FFC52F;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.125em;  /* 18px / 16px */
  }
  
  .container {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
  
  .container h1 {
    font-size: 3.25em;  /* 52 / 16 */
  }
  
  a.button {
    padding: .75em 1.5em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .explanation {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .explanation-right {
    float: none;
    margin: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #sect1 {
    top: 350px;
  }
  
  #phone {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #map {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  
  #sect2 {
    top: 900px;
  }
  
  #rocket {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  #twitter {
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 0em;
  }
  
  #hiddenIcon {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  #mce-EMAIL {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  
  #mc_embed_signup {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.js"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.11/skrollr.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div class="container" id="skrollr-body" data-0="background-color:rgb(0,201,147);" data-400="background-color:rgb(74,173,255);" data-1000="background-color:rgb(74,173,255);" data-1300="background-color:rgb(0,201,147);">
  <h1><i class="icon-circle-blank"></i></h1>
  <h2>PoshFit</h2>
  <p> it's coming to your smartphone </p>

  <a class="arrow" href="#anchor1"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>

  <div class="section" id="sect1">
    <div class="anchor" id="anchor1"></div>
    <div id="hiddenIcon">
      <i class="icon-mobile-phone"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="phone" data-0="margin-left: -20%; opacity:0" data-350="margin-left: 10%; opacity:1">

      <div id="topBar">
        <p>Press---> <i class="icon-bookmark"></i> </p>
      </div>
      <div id="screen">
        <div id="map">
          <img id="placemark" class="notPlacemarked" src="https://s.cdpn.io/52524/CircleMarkerTest3.png">
        </div>
        <!--/ map-->
      </div>
      <!--/ screen-->
    </div>
    <!--/ phone-->
    <div class="explanation" data-300="opacity: 0" data-350="opacity: 1">
      <h2>Right where you are</h2>
      <p>Try on clothes from home. There's no need to travel all the way to the store to find the perfect outfit.</p>
      <a class="arrow" href="#anchor2"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--/ explanation-->
  </div>
  <!--/ sect1-->

  <div class="section" id="sect2">
    <div class="anchor" id="anchor2"></div>
    <div id="hiddenIcon">
      <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="twitter" data-600="margin-top: -20%; opacity: 0" data-1000="margin-top: 0; opacity:1">
      <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="explanation" data-850=" opacity: 0" data-900=" opacity:1">
      <h2>Follow @PoshFit on Twitter</h2>
      <p>Keep up with the latest updates from PoshFit. </p>
      <a class="arrow" href="#anchor3"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--/ explanation-->
  </div>
  <!--sect2-->

  <div class="section" id="sect3">
    <div class="anchor" id="anchor3"></div>
    <div id="hiddenIcon">
      <i class="icon-rocket icon-rotate-180"></i>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="explanation-right" data-1350=" opacity: 0" data-1400=" opacity:1">
      <h2>It's almost here!</h2>
      <p>Leave your email address for our beta newsletter.</p>

      <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

      <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action="">
          <!-- currently empty -->
          <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="me@example.com" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'me@example.com'" required>
          <div><input type="submit" value="I want it!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
    </div>
    <!--/ explanation-->
    <div id="rocket" data-1100="margin-top:-300px; margin-right:0%; opacity: 0" data-1400="margin-top:50; margin-right:20%; opacity:1">
      <i class="icon-rocket icon-rotate-180"></i>
    </div>
    <!--/ rocket-->
  </div>
  <!--sect2-->
  <div class="section" id="footer">
    <p><a href="https://twitter.com/PoshFit">@PoshFit</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/ band-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're animation is ending too late, if you change your `data-1350`,`data-1400` to `data-1050`,`data-1200` it will finish in the right time.

Sorry for the poor solution, i'm still trying to figure a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely helped it show up now, so that is a great relief. Now I just have to figure out how I can get it to transition to the green background and have the rocket scroll in haha.

Comment: The page just isn't scrolling far enough to do its fade out and in transition for the color and it just doesn't scroll all the way in desktop view which is pugging me so hard unless I minimize the browsers height a lot