# Prevent default Firefox from scrolling to anchor tag when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll, anchor-scroll

I have a link to a page that dynamically adds content to a div. What I want to achieve is prevent default browser scrolling to the anchor when the page loads. After searching and trying various solutions found on the web I ended up to the following copied from this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page):

page1.html

```
<a href="url/to/page2/#anchor_name">link to page 2</a>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="load-data-received-from-ajax"></div>
<script>

    var hash = window.location.hash
    var scrollToAnchor = function(hash) {
        // If got a hash
        if (hash) {
            // Scroll to the top (prevention for Chrome)
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            // Anchor element
            var term = $(hash);
            // If element with hash id is defined
            if (term) {
                // Get top offset, including header height
                var scrollto = term.offset().top - 55;
                // Capture id value
                var id = term.attr('id');
                // Capture name value
                var name = term.attr('name');
                // Remove attributes for FF scroll prevention
                term.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name');
                // Scroll to element
                $('html, body, document').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
                // Returning id and name after .5sec for the next scroll
                setTimeout(function() {
                    term.attr('id', id).attr('name', name);
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    };

    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data){
                  $('#data').html(data);
                  scrollToAnchor(hash);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  $('#data').html('There was an error!);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works for Chrome but not for Firefox. On FF the window scrolls to the element defined in hash but when the id attribute is again added to the element, FF scrolls to that point (which does not include the header height). Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: You could change the hash in the url to not exactly match the id found in the element. Appending some constant onto it, for example. Though this might not work for all situations and you'd have to be careful to make sure it doesn't break on reload.

Comment: @suddjian I stored window.location.hash in a global variant (in order to use it later to scroll to the desired point) and completely removed the hash from the url (I did this before the $( document ).ready(function(){}); Still FF behaves the same; as soon as attribute id is added to the element it scrolls there.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `scroll-` prefix to your hash:

```
<a href="url/to/page2/#scroll-anchor-name">link to page 2</a>

<div id="anchor-name">...</div>
```

and at run-time just check and remove it:

```
var hashtpl = "#scroll-";

if (hash && hash.match(RegExp('^' + hashtpl, 'gi')) !== null) {
    hash = "#" + hash.substring(hashtpl.length());
    ...
}
```