# vertical scrollbar jumps in firefox

Tags: firefox, scroll

to perfectly describe the problem look at (in firefox, my version=3.0.10!!):
http://musca-design.de/portfolio.php
when you click through the portfolio, apparently the scrollbar jumps to the bottom?

In Safari, Opera it wont, it stays at the top, which is what I want.

Is there a workaround or how can a tackle the problem?

Comment: All's working with firefox 3.6.12 so I think it's not really a problem. Firefox users usually perform updates.

Comment: I use Firefox 3.6.12 (Linux) and the page jumps.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar (the page actually) jumps, because Firefox jumps to an anchor.
Your links in your `<li>`-list e.g. point to URL#p05 - is there a reason for using those anchors?

Comment: ..maybe use "rel" or "name" attribute of the ancore-tag, does that work?? I have to google :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to prevent this but a solution has been posted here

[Prevent default hash behavior on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503559)