# Set (div id as) .hash to url without page jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hash

i´ve found a jquery snippet to set the divs id as .hash to url, now there is following PROBLEM:

When i scroll the page down everything works fine, but when i scroll from bottom to top the page is jumping (because the divs with the # were set top without any transition)

What i want to have is the possibility to scroll the page without jumps but still adding the hash?

```js
$(document).bind('scroll',function(e){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        if (
            $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 10

            && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 10
        ) {
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hashdiv{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<iframe id="hashone" class="hashdiv"></iframe>

<iframe id="hashtwo" class="hashdiv"></iframe>

<iframe id="hashthree" class="hashdiv"></iframe>

<iframe id="hashfour" class="hashdiv"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503559/prevent-default-hash-behavior-on-page-load

Comment: I cant find any answer in that link, and maybe i dont understand something. but there they try to do something completely different, or? :)

Comment: the marked answer says *There isn't a way to prevent the default hash behaviour* and then explains a work around.

Comment: Ah, now i get it. But with this "work around" it isn´t possible anymore to copy the url for the user. that was the reason why i´m trying that. but thanks – it´s a bgeinning.